# How to open maps using HERE WeGo or Waze instead of Google Maps?

Tags: google-maps, default-applications, google-maps-navigation, maps

I have installed Waze and HERE WeGo on my Moto G4 Plus (Android 6.0.1).

When I search for a street name in Chrome, I get a small map in the search results. When I click on the map, it opens the Google Maps application with the focus on the location that I had searched.

Is there a way to change this so that it will open Waze or HERE WeGo, instead of Google Maps?

I appreciate any help on this issue.